# Array is returning correct results. but shows undefined in HTML display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am having an issue with a project I'm working on. I am using an API to return an array of platforms a video game is on. The array is returning the correct results, however I am having trouble displaying those values in my HTML. The result is just showing undefined.

[image: Website preview]
[image: gamePlatform console log results]

```
// Renders platform information for each game 
const renderPlatformInfo = function (platformResult) {
const gamePlatform = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= `${platformResult.length - 1}`; i++) {
  let getPlatforms = gamePlatform.push(platformResult[i].name);
}

gamePlatform.forEach(function (platformItem) {
  $('.platforms').append(`<li>${platformItem}</li>`)
});

console.log(gamePlatform);
```

};

```
// Renders game information for the searched game
const renderGameInfo = function (gameInfoResult) {
return `<div class="js-game-data row">
                <h2 class="game-name col-12">${gameInfoResult.name}</h2>
                <img src="${gameInfoResult.image.medium_url}" class="game-image col-4" alt="Box art for ${gameInfoResult.name}">
                <ul class="platforms col-6">
                <h3 class="col-12">Original release date:</h3>${gameInfoResult.original_release_date}
                <h3>Platforms:</h3>
                ${renderPlatformInfo(gameInfoResult.platforms)}
                </ul>
                <p class="game-description col-6">${gameInfoResult.deck} <br> <br> <span class="game-details col-12"><b>For more details about the game: <a href="${gameInfoResult.site_detail_url}" target="_blank">Click Here</a></b></span></p>
            </div>
        `;
}
```

Comment: My guess is you are trying to render before the api request has completed. Show more code context

Comment: what if you do *const platformTemp = renderPlatformInfo(gameInfoResult.platforms);* inside renderGameInfo and then *${platformTemp}*

Comment: Note that you can log an empty array to console...then populate the array afterwards and you will see the populated array in the console. It is a live object, not a snapshot

Comment: Your mixing of template literals and jQuery DOM Manipulation is wrong. You call a method and you somehow expect it to find an element that is still in a string and has not been added to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderPlatformInfo` can't append children to a DOM element that doesn't exist yet.  The UL it's trying to select isn't rendered at the time you're trying to append.  Additionally, since `renderPlatformInfo` doesn't return anything, it will always evaluate to `undefined` inside a template literal. If you return an HTML string inside `renderPlatformInfo`, your code should work.  Try something like:

```
let str = '';
gamePlatform.forEach(function(platformItem){
  str += `<li>${platformItem}</li>`;
});
return str;
```

Answer (score 1):

Should *renderPlatformInfo* return something. Are you missing the return there?

Comment: `renderPlatformInfo` is appending `<li>`'s to a list with the `platform.name`.